# Entering two values from user into two different arrays at same index

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a beginnner in c++. I am trying to enter two different values into two different arrays at the same time. but idk why only the second input is being stored in both arrays.

**sample input**

5

110 50

113 100

113 88

43 100

34 34

(two inputs need to be seperated by space)

**my code**

```
int N,K[N],P[N];
cin>>N;   

for(int i=0; i<N;i++)
{ 
    cin >> K[i] >> P[i];
}
```

Comment: Your code cannot even compile since array size should be known at compile time, not to say how you give conclusion that: "only the second input is being stored in both arrays."

Answer (score 1):

This line is nonsense: `int N,K[N],P[N];`
You are asking the compiler to reserve space on the stack for a number that is only known at runtime.

Instead, use `std::vector`, which supports arrays whose size is only known at runtime:

```
int N;
cin>>N;

std::vector<int> K(N),P(N);

for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
  cin >> K[i] >> P[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys I understood the silly mistake I made 